# Unable to override backbutton on every page cordova/phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

As `EventListeners` are bind to `deviceready` event and `deviceready` event is triggered only once when the device is registered, I am unable to override `backbutton` on every page as required by my app.

I tried to search for an answer however couldn't find one. Kindly assist how can this be achieved.

My pages are getting loaded in an `IFrame`

Comment: please note that the back button could be handled on page load . and please provide some research results

Comment: @pouya i have tried handling it on window.onload however the app does not trigger the event.

Comment: have you searched how to call that event in onload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(e){
        BackButton.override();
}, false);
```

Place this code before the closing body tag in your phonegap project.

Tested and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

- `EventListeners` are not bound to `deviceready` event. The default `EventListener` in Cordova is given as an example for catching the `deviceready` event and adding functions when that event occurs.
- We can have `EventListeners` at any point of time in the code when we want the events to be caught and want some actions to be performed on them.

So add them in the `<script>` tag or `JavaScript` file of new pages where u redirect users.

```
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

    function onBackKeyDown(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       alert('Back Button is Pressed!');
    }
```

Refer [this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/cordova/events/events.html#backbutton) page for more details.